# Audit Logging in SharePoint MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, logging, audit

We want to be able to view an audit of changes to groups/members/user profiles within MOSS. Can we do this out of the box or would we need a 3rd party tool?

Is everything within MOSS audited somewhere or just certain aspects of it?

All the best

Answer (score 0):

The following options are available out of the box under Site Settings > Site collection audit settings:

Documents and Items

- Opening or downloading documents,
  viewing items in lists, or viewing
  item properties
- Editing items
- Checking out or checking in items
- Moving or copying items to another
  location in the site
- Deleting or restoring items

Lists, Libraries, and Sites

- Editing content types and columns
- Searching site content
- Editing users and permissions

The last option, Editing users and permissions, might get you what you want for users.